# self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=true; Vs [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

What is the difference between these two statements.
For hiding navigation bar I am using one of these statement to hide navigation bar in viewWillAppear method as given below:

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=true;   //works....
}

 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES]; //doesn't work...
}
```

This code works fine with self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=true; but when I use [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES]; It doesn't works.Why so ?

Sorry Friends there was a mistake in question.Now corrected please see again

Answer (score 4):

FWIW, I encountered a situation today in iOS 6 where:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

appeared to have zero effect. What did work is:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

Comment: what is more fantastic is that I have used millions of times `self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;` but this one time, it is not working and `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];` is. I love this buggy stuff apple pushes around. For God's sake Apple. T H A N K S.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is one hides it and other shows it :)

```
YES = TRUE 
NO = FALSE
```

**Hides the nav bar**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=TRUE;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
```

**Shows the nav bar**

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=FALSE;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

**self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;**

This will only hide the  BackButton of navigation bar.

**self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = false;**

This will hide the navigation bar including its BackButton.

**self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = true;**

This will enable the navigation bar.

**self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;**

This will enable the  BackButton of navigation bar (untill navigation bar is set to hidden).

Answer (score 0):

This code: `self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;` actually hides the back button

which display on navigation bar. This code:

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=false;
```

actually don't hide your navigation bar it display navigation bar on your top of view.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code would work changing YES to NO

You can use setNavigationBarHidden:animated: works for me.

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to hide the navigationBar, you should use this:-

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

Or

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

And it works fine each time.

And your case should work fine anyway, but as we all can see, it's just some internal inconsistency of iOS.